# How to show photos in Dropbox Chooser window by default?

Tags: ajax, dropbox, dropbox-api, mashup

My application accepts photographs from end-users. They will most likely select pictures that are recently taken. The initial view of Chooser, which shows the file structure of the user's Dropbox folder is therefore far less useful compared to the Photos view. Is there a parameter than can be passed to make the window opens to that view? Just a matter of saving an inevitable click.

I tried to examine the source code but the library appears to be written in Coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to open a specific folder in the Dropbox Chooser. You can make the UI a bit nicer by using the `extensions` option to specify only image file types.

Comment: Just to add: there's also no way to select the photos view versus the files view.

Comment: Is Dropbox considering adding it? Setting 'extensions' is useful for preventing mistake, but presenting the end-user a list of file that he can't select is sort of weak from a friendliness standpoint.